# No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/imagick". OpenSSL Error?

Tags: php, docker, pear, pecl

I apologise if this is a duplicate, but none of the already posted question's answers helped me.

Recently, the Dockerfile for our `php5.6-apache` doesn't want to build anymore. The line where it fails is when `imagick` is trying to be installed via `pecl`.

```
# Enable imagick
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN yes '' | pecl install -vvv imagick-beta
```

Running this line fails due to the following error:

```
 > [12/25] RUN yes '' | pecl -vvv install imagick-beta:
#0 1.354 
#0 1.354 Warning: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
#0 1.354 error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 183
#0 1.355 
#0 1.355 Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 183
#0 1.357 
#0 1.357 Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://pecl.php.net:443 (Unknown error) in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 183
#0 1.359 No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/imagick"
#0 1.360 Cannot initialize 'channel://pecl.php.net/imagick-beta', invalid or missing package file
#0 1.362 Package "channel://pecl.php.net/imagick-beta" is not valid
#0 1.366 install failed
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yes '' | pecl -vvv install imagick-beta" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

The only recent post I found about someone having the same issue is [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81078) but I'm not sure about the channel where I'd see any updates on fixing this bug. In the bug report the last person states the following:

> Certificate expiry is set to yesterday. I'm thinking about all docker build pipelines currently failing all over the world <3

Does he mean about `php.net`'s SSL certificate? Because when I checked it it looks valid so I don't understand why it can not connect.

line 183 of `PEAR/proxy.php` is the following:

```
$fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);
```

So if I understand correctly, the docker container can not establish a proper connection via `pecl.php.net:443`? Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Thanks in advance for any (constructive) answers!

Comment: SSL cert has expired again today, how fun..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the fix that finally got everything working:

```
FROM php:alpine AS cacert

FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine # Image that the container is actually using

COPY --from=cacert /etc/ssl /root/ssl

RUN mv /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf* /root/ssl && rm -rf /etc/ssl && mv /root/ssl /etc/ssl \
  && pear update-channels \
  && pear upgrade
```

From what I understand the CA cert is expired in older versions of PHP images and need to be replaced with a newer one. This might be a bit of hack but it will get you through until the older images' CA certs will be updated.

Comment: Worked like a charm, fixed my php:5.6-fpm-alpine container.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it indicates that the `SSL` certificate verification failed, to fix it you can try disabling SSL certificate verification in the Dockerfile by adding this line before the `pecl` install command!

```
RUN pecl config-set "disable-tls" "yes"
```

or you can also updating the `SSL` certificate for `pecl.php.net`

good luck!

Comment: This command is throwing another error for me: failed to solve: `process "/bin/sh -c pecl config-set \"disable-tls\" \"yes\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1`. How could I update the SSL certificate when in a Docker environment?

Comment: @Narc0t1CYM because you must add this command to your Dockerfile before running the `pecl config-set` `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php-pear`

Comment: if it's not work again add this line before the `pecl install` command in your Dockerfile: `pear config-set http:verify false`

Comment: and to replace the old SSL certificate file with the new one. You can copy the new SSL certificate file to the container using the `docker cp` command for example `docker cp new.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this problem by installing the packages directly from the project's git repository.

```
FROM php:7.0-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache imagemagick-dev libtool make g++

RUN wget https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6/archive/refs/tags/6.9.12-28.tar.gz && \
     tar -xzf 6.9.12-28.tar.gz && \
     cd ImageMagick6-6.9.12-28 && \
     ./configure && \
     make && \
     make install

RUN wget https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.4.4.tgz && \
     tar -xzf imagick-3.4.4.tgz && \
     cd imagick-3.4.4 && \
     phpize && \
     ./configure --with-imagick=/usr/local && \
     make && \
     make install

RUN echo "extension=imagick.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/imagick.ini
```